# express x+N with the formula of length $O(\log N)$

Tags: logic, algorithms, first-order-logic

Consider the set of natural numbers $\Bbb N$ as a signature structure $(=, S)$, where $S$
is interpreted as a function of $S(x) = x+ 1$. Prove that the two-place relation y = x + N can
be expressed by the formula of this signature, the length of which is $O(\log N)$.

It is clear that the predicate x + N can always be expressed in terms of the function $S$ by the formula of length $O(N)$, but how to do this by the ratio of length $O(\log N)$?

And is it even possible?

Comment: I think you have a typo in the next to last paragraph, where $x + \mathbb N$ should presumably be $x + N$.  Is $N$ a fixed number for the purpose of the writing "the predicate $x +N$".  Literally speaking that is an expression (term) and not in the first instance a predicate.  Perhaps you want a formula for a predicate provably equivalent to $y = x + N$?  Would a recursively defined predicate satisfy the requirement?

Comment: If you had a formula implementing addition, you could use it to build a defining formula for $N$ based on the binary representation of $N$.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean quantifier depth instead of length? That would be less surprising.

Comment: I think it's possible as stated, because $y=x+2N$ can be written as $\exists z\forall s\forall t((s=x\land t=z)\lor(s=z\land t=y)\to t=s+N).$

Comment: @hardmath Its true, thats a typo, I fixed it, and you are right the goal is to write a formula equivalent to this predicate. And if you give a recursive definition of the predicate x = y + N, then I can definitely say if it is suitable or not

Comment: @RobArthan that is the problem from from the logic workshop.

Comment: @TomKern no, the problem is correctly formulated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to build $N$ by doubling, which takes $O(\log N)$ steps. We can write a formula expressing $y=x+2n$ (or $y=x+2n+1$) using a formula expressing $y=x+n$ and some logical connectives to "apply it twice" while only writing it once:
$$
\begin{align}
\phi_{2n}(x,y)&:=\exists z\ \forall s\forall t\ (s=x\land t=z)\lor(s=z\land t=y)\to\phi_n(s,t)\\
\phi_{2n+1}(x,y)&:=\exists z\ \phi_{2n}(x,z)\land y=S(z)
\end{align}
$$

using fresh variable names at each stage in place of $z,s,t$ to avoid collisions with subformulas.